# Can't write the content of a file in UserData AWS EC2 cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, user-data, cloud-init

I want to get the content of a file in the UserData without providing inline content as following, but I'm getting the path of the file in the content when the ec2 boots instead of the content of the file.

Here's a snippet of my template:

```
  ServiceInstance:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Instance"
    Properties:
      . . . 
      UserData:
        'Fn::Base64': !Sub |
          #cloud-config
          write_files:
            - path: /etc/sysconfig/cloudformation
              permissions: 0644
              owner: root
              content: |
                STACK_NAME=${AWS::StackName}
                AWS_REGION=${AWS::Region}
            - path: /etc/path-to-file/conf.yaml
              permissions: 0644
              owner: root
              content: "@file://./config/conf-${Env}.yaml"
          runcmd:
            ## run some commands
```

when I ssh to ec2 and check the file content I get this:

```
[ec2-user@ec2ip ~]$ cat /etc/path-to-file/conf.yaml
@file://./config/conf-dev.yaml
```

I checked this [cloud init docs](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#write-files), but can't find something related.
any idea what did I do wrong in here ?

Answer (score 0):

Encode the file content in base64 and pass it as argument. Cloud Init will decode the string **b64**.
Be careful of the cloudformation size limits on template and variables.

```
Parameters:
  ConfContent:
    Type: String
    Description: "Conf content in base64 format."

Resources:
  ServiceInstance:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Instance"
    Properties:
      . . . 
      UserData:
        'Fn::Base64': !Sub
          - |
            #cloud-config
            write_files:
              - path: /etc/sysconfig/cloudformation
                permissions: 0644
                owner: root
                content: |
                  STACK_NAME=${AWS::StackName}
                  AWS_REGION=${AWS::Region}
              - path: /etc/path-to-file/conf.yaml
                permissions: 0644
                owner: root
                content: ${CONF_CONTENT}
                encoding: b64
            runcmd:
              ## run some commands
          - CONF_CONTENT: !Ref ConfContent
```

Then expose the file content as property :

```
aws cloudformation create-stack \
  --stack-name "mystack" \
  --template-body "template.yaml" \
  --parameters \
    ParameterKey=ConfContent,ParameterValue=\"$(base64 -w0 ./config/conf-dev.yaml)\"
```